# If ‎$‎f(x+c)‎$ ‎is ‎$‎\log‎$‎-convex, then ‎$‎f(x)‎$ ‎is ‎$‎\log‎$‎-convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

‎Let the function ‎$‎f(x+c)‎$ ‎is ‎$‎\log‎$‎-‎convex ‎on ‎interval ‎‎‎$‎I‎$‎, ‎where ‎‎$‎c‎\neq ‎0‎$ ‎is a‎ ‎real ‎number. ‎My ‎queistion ‎is:‎

‎
Is ‎‎$‎f(x)‎$ ‎ ‎log‎-convex?‎

‎
I know that if ‎$‎f(x)‎$ ‎is ‎‎$\log$‎-‎convex on a certain interval‎‎‎‎, and if ‎$‎c\neq 0‎$ ‎is ‎any ‎real ‎number‎, then the function ‎$‎f(x+c)‎$ ‎is ‎‎$‎\log‎$‎-convex on ‎the ‎corresponding ‎intervals. ‎Thanks.‎

Comment: $f(x+c)$ is not a function but a real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=f(x+c-c)$ and $-c \neq 0$. So the result follows from what you know.